# Mostrar Valor Promedio de el dia anterior entre fecha

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy haciendo una consulta entre fechas, en donde quiero mostrar el valor promedio, pero de el día anterior al escogido, tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$desde = $_POST['desde'];
$hasta = $_POST['hasta'];
$estacion=2;
$registro = ("SELECT  AVG(TS) as TsueloProm1
             FROM sensores 
             WHERE date BETWEEN '$desde'
             AND '$hasta'
             AND date=date(date(now())-1) 
             AND idestacion='$estacion' ");
$resultado = $conexion->query($registro);
```

entonces por ej: cuando escojo la fecha '$desde'(02-11-2017) y '$hasta'(05-11-2017), en la variable '$desde' debería escoger el día anterior al escogido, osea (01-11-2017), y con esa consulta me arroja error, por favor si me pueden ayudar con eso.

Comment: Que error te da.. esta linea suena rara: date=date(date(now())-1)

Comment: hola gbianchi, me da el siguiente error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in "mis carpetas" on line 41, y no me muestra ningun resultado.

Comment: y cual es la linea 41?? por favor usa [edit], y agrega toda la informacion relevante a la pregunta ahi dentro. Tambien, prueba si el sql que estas haciendo anda.